# python socket, client not receiving data in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

So i'm writing a TCP based code in python that send 2 variables (username and password) from client and server receives those 2 variables and based on those variables, it does something, but my problem is that my client doesn't receive the second variable!

#### Client code:

```
# Variables
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6767
username = "User"
password = "1234"

# Connect To Server
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((ip, port))

# Send Information to Server
information_message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
while True:
    if information_message == 'PASSWORD':
        client.send(password.encode('ascii'))
        print(information_message)
    if information_message == 'USERNAME':
        client.send(username.encode('ascii'))
        print(information_message)
    break
```

#### Server code:

```
import socket

# Connection Data
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 6767

# Starting Server
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

# receive information to client
while True:
    client, address = server.accept()
    client.send('PASSWORD'.encode('ascii'))
    password = client.recv(10240).decode('ascii')
    client.send('USERNAME'.encode())
    username = client.recv(10240).decode('ascii')
    print(username, password)
    break
```

expect on server.py:

```
user 1234
```

real output on server.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\test\server.py", line 29, in <module>
    username = client.recv(10240).decode('ascii')
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

i know that only ('PASSWORD') will send as a data to client but i can't understand why it won't send the second data ('USERNAME')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
information_message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
while True:
    if information_message == 'PASSWORD':
        client.send(password.encode('ascii'))
        print(information_message)
    if information_message == 'USERNAME':
        client.send(username.encode('ascii'))
        print(information_message)
    break
```

The last `break` statement causes your client to exit the loop immediately after the first `information_message` was processed, i.e. after `PASSWORD`. At the moment the server writes `USERNAME` to the socket, this socket is thus already closed by the client. While the `send` might still succeed (it might also fail with `Broken Pipe` already) the following `recv` will fail since the socket is closed.

What you likely want to do is something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        information_message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
    except:
        break

    if information_message == 'PASSWORD':
        client.send(password.encode('ascii'))
        print(information_message)
    if information_message == 'USERNAME':
        client.send(username.encode('ascii'))
        print(information_message)
```